# arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, ndk-build

first of all, I'm sorry for bad type English.
I want to compile an old source with NDK and cocos2d in windows.

this is my command line:

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 -C "G:/coc/androiddev/dpsg_android/proj.android" "NDK_MODULE_PATH=G:/coc/androiddev/cocos2dx:G:/coc/androiddev/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt"
```

and this is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeRQD
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/armeabi/libNativeRQD.so  
LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GLIBCXX_PERMIT_BACKWARD_HASH -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

FILE_LIST := $(LOCAL_PATH)/DPSGApp/main.cpp
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Common/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/protobuf-2.4.1/src/google/protobuf/*.cc)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/protobuf-2.4.1/src/google/protobuf/io/*.cc)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/protobuf-2.4.1/src/google/protobuf/stubs/*.cc)
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/snappy-1.0.5/snappy-sinksource.cc
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/snappy-1.0.5/snappy-stubs-internal.cc
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/NetWork/snappy-1.0.5/snappy.cc
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/buffer.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/evbuffer.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/evdns.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/event.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/event_tagging.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/evutil.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/http.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/log.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/poll.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/epoll.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/select.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/signal.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/strlcpy.c
FILE_LIST += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../rpc/proto/msg.pb.cc
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/net/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Graphics/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/GameFramework/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes/GameLogic/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes/GameCenter/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Connections/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/GAI/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../engine/src/Patcher/*.cpp)
FILE_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../engine/src/Patcher/7zDependencies/*.c)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Common 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/android
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/compat
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/net
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/protobuf-2.4.1
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/protobuf-2.4.1/src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/snappy-1.0.5
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Network/src
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../rpc/proto
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/platform
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libxml2/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/platform/android
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/cocoa
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/kazmath/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Graphics
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/extensions
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/shaders
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/support/zip_support
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/touch_dispatcher
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/text_input_node
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/extensions/GUI/CCEditBox
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/extensions/GUI/CCControlExtension
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/CocosDenshion/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/GameFramework
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes/GameLogic
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Classes/GameCenter
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/Connections
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../client/dpsg/GAI
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../engine/src/Patcher


LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev)
$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx)
$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/CocosDenshion/android)
$(call import-add-path, $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../androiddev/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt)


$(call import-module,cocos2dx)
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android)
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

first, everything is compiling good, but after a few minutes, I give "**arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory**" error.

I searched on google, stack overflow, cocos2d forum, but no any any any result.

I'm confused.

Check my image for more information:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNV7P.jpg

Best Regards.

Comment: Double check for any paths/filenames with spaces in them, it just can't cope. I can't see any in the above but it is worth checking.  Also try running `ndk_build` adding `V=1`  you could also try adding `NDK_LOG=1` but this produces a lot of output (mostly internal details).

Comment: Actually, now I found when adding NDK_DEBUG=1 parameter, i give "arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory" error, but when without NDK_DEBUG=1, everything is fine. what's mean:-?